# commit the same repository to github and svn

Tags: svn, github, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a project which is a github repository and a svn repository (unfuddle)

Currently I use sourcetree to commit and push to github and a different program to commit and push the same changes to the svn repository.

Can I use sourcetree to work on both repos?

Comment: Sourcetree can be made to work with subversion but it's a tricky process, probably better to look at something like subgit: http://subgit.com/ - You can use that to push any changes made to the git repository automatically to the svn repository.

Comment: why would you wish to have two different repositories?

Comment: Working with some people on the project with unfuddle and my local work is done on github